# Function inside DF Query pandas getting error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, lambda

Trying to count date of a col `(['Call Start Time'])` of `df0` using lambda function instead of for.

The 1st line below gave this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Load' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Tried to convert the `Call Start Time.date()` part using a def function, below. But that's wrong as well. How can i rectify this?

```
df0.query('`Call Start Time`.date()=="13-07-20"').shape[0]    

def random_to_date(x):
    y=pd.Timestamp(x)
    z=y.date()
    return z    

df0.query('random_to_date(df0['Call Start Time'])=="13-07-20"').shape[0]
```

Comment: Are you trying to literally count how many occurrences of a given date are in your DataFrame? That's kind of how the question reads but it's confused.

Answer (score 0):

In random_to_date function Timestamp() accepts only str,int, float values. But you passed a expression, also query() accepts only expressions. Thats why you are facing error.